# How to use tokenize function in Mapforce to split String

Tags: string, tokenize, map-force

I recently started to learn about the MapForce application and I noticed that there is "**tokenize**" method which user input String and delimiter. But it returns only first token only.

My problem is how can I access all the tokens from "**tokenize**" method?

[This is the MapForced map which I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVkSn.png)

[This is the output that I got for above mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW4WF.png)

I noticed that there is warning saying that it took only first token and ignore the rest. I need to know how can I take those tokens in to output String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the tokenize method it will return the all the tokens but when you pass it to a result it will only take first token. But if you see below example in normal process it will return all the tokens then apply the concat function for each token.

[image]

Out put would be **A1 B1 C1 D1**

Comment: Thanks Coder for the explanation I did not try to use it in another process. Just try to get in out put. This works :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the functions **first-items** and **skip-first-items** (if necessary repeatedly) [image: Example]